# raster:: extract produces an empty list

Tags: r, raster, lidar

I am trying to extract the values of pixels in a DSM(CHM) within digitized tree crowns.

first I set my working directory read in the shapefile and raster.

```
TreeCrowns <-shapefile("plot1sag_shape/plot1sag.shp")
CHM <- raster('272280split4.tif')
```

Then I try to extract the pixel values

```
pixel <- raster::extract(CHM, TreeCrowns, method= 'simple', weights=FALSE, fun=NULL)
```

But I get an empty list with all NULL values for every polygon. I have confirmed that the CHM and polygons are in the same location. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your shapefile consists of polygon, the `extract()` function need to know how to summarise the pixel values across a polygon via the `fun=` argument. Since you provide `fun=NULL`, the function interpret as returning `NULL` values to summarise the pixel values.

Try `fun=mean` or `fun=sum` (and they mean different thing so see which one suits you).

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I have "fun=mean" and it's still empty... I also checked if the projections are the same and they are. Any other idea of what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

That probably happens because the polygons and the raster do not overlap. Can you `show(CHM)` and `TreeCrowns`? Have you looked at

```
plot(CHM)
lines(TreeCrowns)
```

Or are your polygons very small relative to the raster cells? In that case try argument `small=TRUE`